# SQL query to join column with multiple ids

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to connect a initiative table with locations one, there is a column at initiative table which ill contain multiple ids or single ids, depends on how much is added. The data will be saved like this:
"1,4,3"

```
public function getallRIS(){

        $connect = $this->connect;

        /*
        THIS QUERY WORKS WITHOUT MULTIPLE IDS ON THE COLUMN
        $qx = "SELECT initiatives.location_id as init_location, initiatives.name as init_name, initiatives.startyear as init_startyear, initiatives.endyear as init_endyear, ST_AsText(locations.location) as locations_coord, locations.name as locations_name 
        FROM locations 
        JOIN initiatives on  initiatives.location_id = locations.id";
        */

        $qx = "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(initiatives.location_id SEPARATOR ',') as init_location, initiatives.name as init_name, initiatives.startyear as init_startyear, initiatives.endyear as init_endyear, ST_AsText(locations.location) as locations_coord, locations.name as locations_name 
        FROM locations 
        JOIN initiatives
        ON FIND_IN_SET(locations.id, initiatives.location_id)
        GROUP BY initiatives.location_id";

        $queryx = "SELECT ST_AsText(ri_location) FROM ri;";
        if($query = $connect->query($qx)){  }else{ echo $connect->error; }
        $count = $query->num_rows;
        $row = 1;
        while($fetch = $query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

            $point = $fetch['locations_coord'];
            $point = str_replace(array("POINT(",")"),array("",""),$point);
            $point = str_replace(" ",",",$point);


               $coord = explode(",",$point);    
               $lat = $coord[0];
               $long = $coord[1];

               echo'
                {
                  lat: '.$lat.',
                  lng: '.$long.',
                  text: "'; echo "<b style='font-size:17px;'>"; echo''.$fetch['init_name'].'</b><br>Country: '.$fetch['locations_name'].'<br>Info: '; echo"<a href=''>"; echo'View</a><br>Start Year: '.$fetch['init_startyear'].'<br>End Year: '.$fetch['init_endyear'].'"
                },
               ';



            $row++;
        }

    }
```

However is not working properly , shows only first item of each column

Comment: storing multiple data in a single cell is a symptom of a poor database design. And you r issue is one of the best examples of why you shouldn't

Comment: @LelioFaieta So what you mean, should i create another table and store there the locations id and just store the id of that table ?

Comment: No. you should maintain a one to many table with all the id: one id for each row and the same  key for each id

Comment: @LelioFaieta That's what i specified , let me type clear to see if i got it right, i should make a relational table, which ill contain the id,initiative_id, location_id , then instead of having a column of the locations, i simply load from that t able all locations id from where the initiative_id is equal to